# How mock stripe in Django unit test

Tags: django, unit-testing, stripe-payments

We used stripe for the payment system.
Imagine a user is doing different things in our system and for each part, he has to pay. We send these payments to Stripe by calling:

```
stripe.InvoiceItem.create()
```

Then we create and finalize the invoice for him by calling:

```
invoice=stripe.Invoice.create()
stripe.Invoice.finalize_invoice(invoice.id)
```

So if the user has to pay for 3 items:

```
item1 = 1
item2 = 2
item3 = 3
```

The finalize_invoice will have an id, total, ...., and:

```
total = 6
```

To test if all items are sending the correct amount to Stripe, I'd like to check the total.

In order to test our payment system, I had to mock Stripe, but the Stripe invoice total would always be zero.

I mocked **stripe.InvoiceItem.create** and **stripe.Invoice.finalize_invoice** and **stripe.Invoice.create** like this:

```
@patch("app_name.models.stripe.InvoiceItem.create")
@patch("app_name.models.stripe.Invoice.finalize_invoice")
@patch("app_name.models.stripe.Invoice.create")
def test_method(
    self,
    mock_create,
    mock_finalize,
    mock_invoice_item,
):
    response = MagicMock()
    # api_key and stripe_account from this link https://stripe.com/docs/api/connected_accounts
    response.api_key = "sk_test_MSc53AbTknQXPy"
    response.stripe_account = "acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C"  # Stripe account ID
    # last version here https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades
    response.stripe_version = "2022-08-01" 
    mock_invoice_item.return_value = response

    response = MagicMock()
    response.total = 20
    response.invoice_pdf = "https://google.com"
    response.id = "sk_test_MSc53AbTknQXPy"
    mock_create.return_value = response
    mock_finalize.return_value = response.id
```

Stripe might have a mocking feature.
Stripe-mock was not clear to me how to use it in unit tests.

Comment: Can you not just use the Upcoming Invoice features of Stripe's API with a Test Mode API key?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know how you are mocking the different Stripe functions in order to pinpoint the issue with the the invoice total cost.

If you're thinking of using `stripe-mock`, I guess the best way to handle unit testing is to do so in an agnostic way (regardless of the stack), by running the `stripe-mock` Docker as described in the github [Readme](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock/blob/master/README.md) and create a proxy that will route any API call to the Docker URL instead of the actual API URL (https://api.stripe.com). This will allow you to do unit testing locally on your machine and even with your preferred CI/CD.

With that being said, please bear in mind that there are some known limitations described in the Readme doc.

Comment: I installed go with this command:
sudo snap install go --classic
then I used this command to install stripe-mock:
go install github.com/stripe/stripe-mock@latest
but stripe-mock command is not working:(

Comment: I don't know how I can ask for help with this question if it hasn't been solved yet. All small parts of the payment are sent to Stripe and Stripe gives the total back to the user. How can I test if this number is OK or not in our unit test?

Comment: I really don't understand the use case. let's forget for a sec about the unit testing. what are you trying to verify?

Comment: I edited the question. I'm awful at asking questions. I hope it's understandable. I have been trying to resolve this problem for over a month without success.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe API responses can be mocked conveniently using `unittest.mock`, dictionaries and `stripe.convert_to_stripe_object`:

```
@patch("app_name.models.stripe.Invoice.retrieve")
def test_method(self, mock_retrieve):

    data = {
        "id": "sk_test_1234",
        "total": 20,
        "invoice_pdf": "https://example.com/invoice.pdf",
    }

    mock_retrieve.return_value = stripe.convert_to_object(
        data, 
        stripe_version="2022-08-01"
    )
```